# How to put different position to randomly added image? Vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

**I have this:** On every second, all images move to the **same** random position [image: screenshot]

**But I want this:** On every second, I have a new image in a different position

*JavaScript:*

```
const vue = require("@/assets/images/vue.png");
const bootstrap = require("@/assets/images/bootstrap.png");
const bulma = require("@/assets/images/bulma.png");

export default {
  name: "randImg",
  data() {
    return {
      images: [
        vue,
        bootstrap,
        bulma,
        css3
      ],
      addedImage: [],
      imgTop: -100,
      imgLeft: -100,
      imgHeight: 64,
      imgWidth: 64,
      changeInterval: 1000,
      selectedImage: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    imgStyle() {
      return {
        top: `${this.imgTop}px`,
        left: `${this.imgLeft}px`,
        height: `${this.imgHeight}px`,
        width: `${this.imgWidth}px`
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.randomImage();
    const randomImg = func => setInterval(func, this.changeInterval);
    randomImg(this.randomImage);
    randomImg(this.addImage);
    randomImg(this.randomPosition);
  },
  methods: {
    randomImage() {
      const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.images.length);
      this.selectedImage = this.images[idx];
    },
    randomPosition() {
      const randomPos = twoSizes => Math.round(Math.random() * twoSizes);
      this.imgTop = randomPos(window.innerHeight - this.imgHeight);
      this.imgLeft = randomPos(window.innerWidth - this.imgWidth);
    },
    addImage(){
      this.addedImage.push(this.selectedImage);
    }
  }
}
```

*HTML:*

```
<img :style="imgStyle" class="image" :key="id" :src="image" v-for=" (image,id) in addedImage">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your images are bound to the same computed `imgStyle`, which sets the position to the same coordinates for all bound images.

To make the positions unique, each `addImage[]` item should contain its own position:

```
this.addImage.push({
  style: {
    top: `${this.imgTop}px`,
    left: `${this.imgLeft}px`,
    height: `${this.imgHeight}px`,
    width: `${this.imgWidth}px`
  },
  src: this.selectedImage
})
```

This will require updating the template to bind to sub-properties of each iterator item:

```
<img :style="image.style" 
     :src="image.src" 
     v-for="image in addedImage">
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/YgBeRz)